# Parse a large XML file and get the duplicate attributes

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a large `XML` file. It is structured like below:

```
...
<LexicalEntry id="tajaAhul_$axoS_1">
  <Lemma partOfSpeech="n" writtenForm="تجاهُل شخْص"/>
  <Sense id="tajaAhul_$axoS_1_&lt;homaAl_$axoS_n1AR" synset="&lt;homaAl_$axoS_n1AR"/>
  <WordForm formType="root" writtenForm="جهل"/>
</LexicalEntry>
...
```

The file has been created automatically, so it may contain a duplicate `writtenForm`. I want to parse it with `JAVA` to check if there is really a duplicate `writtenForm` and if so I want to get them. With `JAVA`, the more I read about parsing `XML` files the more I get confused! I found that if the file is a large one, I should use `SAX Parser` but I am not familiar with all his functions and methods and I also found that with `SAX Parser`, I should create all the work in some `handler class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned your XML is large, the best option to parse is the SAX parser as you have already found out. It's not as scary as you assume. It reads through your XML content and calls your "Handler" to handle what it "sees" in the XML. Your handler class will be the one that will 'capture' and structure the XML content. Because it reads 'through' your XML it doesn't consume memory to store the content of XML. There are many examples out there on SAX parsing but this could be a starter [example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax-example.html). Good luck!